# How does the number of self-avoiding paths between two points scale, in a square/cubic lattice?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, asymptotics

Consider two different infinite graphs, whose vertices are drawn from $\mathbb Z^2$ or $\mathbb Z^3$. Let $P_d : \mathbb Z^d \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ for $d \in \{2,3\}$ be the function such that $P_d(\mathbf x,n)$ to the number of paths (*i.e.* walks in which every vertex is visited only once; also known in some contexts as a self-avoiding path) of length $n$ from the origin to $\mathbf x \in \mathbb Z$.

From [the Wikipedia article on self-avoiding paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk), exactly computing [the sum of] $P_d(\mathbf x,n)$ for all $n$ is likely to be difficult if we restrict ourselves to a finite rectangular region of the lattice — the latter problem is conjectured to be **NP**-hard. However, do we know how $P_d(\mathbf x,n)$ scales, *e.g.* in terms of the coefficients $x_j$ of $\mathbf x$, as well as $n$?

Comment: Not NP, #P-hard.

Comment: Fair point; perhaps the correct statement would be that determining whether the function exceeds some threshold is conjectured to be **NP**-hard. I have no intuition either way, and in any case am concerned with asymptotics rather than the exact problem.